# Set an OnClick listener for an included layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm developing an android app in Kotlin and I'm using View Binding.

I've included a layout inside a ConstraintLayout, like this:

```xml
<include
    android:id="@+id/item_salon_profile"
    layout="@layout/item_salon_profile" 
    ... />
```

The included layout has some TextView inside and a background.

The element `binding.itemSalonProfile` is a `ItemSalonProfileBinding` (and not a `View`), so I'm not able to set the listener in the usual way: `binding.itemSalonProfile.setOnClickListener{ }`.

How can I set an OnClick Listener for the whole included layout?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was as simple as:

```kotlin
binding.root.setOnClickListener{ }
```